# Can I apply for two extended visas in Schengen countries at once?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, applications, long-stay-visas

I am a US citizen trying to stay in Europe for a year.  I want to live in either Spain or Portugal.  Can I apply to both countries at the same time in case one does not give me the extended visa?  I'm not trying to get two visas.  Just trying to cover my behind.

Comment: Applications are recorded in the Schengen Visa Information System. Submitting two might flag up as duplicates https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en

Comment: Don't try to game the system.

Comment: @Traveller National visa applications are not recorded in VIS.

Comment: @Natbee Do you fulfill the requirements for a long-term visa? It is not foreseen for a tourist to stay that long in Spain or Portugal. You will have to take up residency and therefore fufill a lot more requirements than a 'plain' tourist.

Comment: Yes.  I am not going as a tourist.  I am going as a pensioner.

Comment: I'm not trying to game the system.  I am asking if I can do this legitimately.